# Retrieving elements from embedded array in mgo (golang+MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm using golang in the backend and mongoDB as database. When I try to retrieve documents from one of the embedded array I'm getting only one index of the embedded array in the result as the result.

My struct is like this

```
type (
    Employee struct {
        Name           string
        EmpId          string
        Password       string
        Leave        []*LeaveInfo
    }
LeaveInfo struct {

        Id              int
        Days            float64
        From            time.Time
        To              time.Time
        AppliedDate     time.Time
        Status          string
        ApprovedDate    time.Time
    }
```

My golang code is

```
   t := time.Date(2016, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    var result []*Employee
        if e := c.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"leave": bson.M{
            "$elemMatch": bson.M{
                "from": bson.M{
               "$gte":t, 
    },
            },
        },
        },
        ).All(&result); e != nil {
            fmt.Println(e)
}
```

My database structure is

```
_id:57d7a6673897593ae84bed49{
Name:"Mark"
EmpId:"E123"
Password:1234
Leave:[
{
    "id" : 0,
    "days" : 1.5,
    "from" : ISODate("2016-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "to"   : ISODate("2016-12-02T12:00:00Z"),
    "applieddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Approved",
    "approveddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),

  },
{

    "id" : 1,
    "days" : 2.0,
    "from" : ISODate("2016-12-11T00:00:00Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2016-12-12T00:00:00Z"),
    "applieddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Approved",
    "approveddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),

  },
]
}
```

In this I m getting only the index 0 of the Leave array.As you can see both the index of the array have date greater than t.But when i retreive it I m getting only one index (index 0).But what i need is to retreive all the index which has date greater than t.Please help me.thanks

My result is as follows

```
{
    "Name": "",

    "EmpId": "",
    "Password": "",
"Leave": [
      {

        "Id": 0,
        "Days": 1.5,
        "from" : ISODate("2016-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "to"   : ISODate("2016-12-02T12:00:00Z"),
        "applieddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "status" : "Approved",
        "approveddate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'd better use `$unwind` to unfold the array and `$match` to filter out the required "leave" from there on

Comment: Thanks.Implemented and got the desired result.Will post the answer now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that what you ask is possible in a single mongo query. I would rather get all
elements and the filter in go with something like this:

```
var result []*Employee
err := c.Find(nil).All(&result)
if err != nil {
    // do stuff...
}

// For each result, filter the Leave values having a to small From value.
t := time.Date(2016, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
for i := range result {
    var j int
    for j < len(result[i].Leave) {
        if result[i][j].From.Before(t) {
            result[i] = append(result[i][:j], result[i][j+1:]...)
            continue
        }
        j++
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I found that by implementing the $unwind,$match,$project this can be implemented.Now i have got the result that i need.Once Again thanks for your effort.....I will post my answer now.Thanks